# Does running dbcc checkdb on the restored backup file be an alternative to running dbcc checkdb on that server?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2022

I have 2 node AG server.

Say db name is TestDb.

Dbcc checkdb is run on TestDb weekly on both servers.

Daily full and hourly log backups run on secondary server. After backup th, db is restored and dbcc checkdb is run against the restored db.

I was wondering if it is OK to stop dbcc checkdb on the server on which backup runs? Because since the backup runs on that server, and it is restored and dbcc checkdb is run on it.

Comment: you may find your answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240375/can-a-full-dbcc-checkdb-operation-be-safely-offloaded-to-a-restored-backup-on-a

Comment: So in AG Setup it is safe to not perform dbcc checkdb on the server from which I do the backup (against which dbcc checkdb is performed)?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is an older post... I feel that this is still the best advice... (https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-consistency-checking-options-for-a-vldb/)

The first choice should always be to use the Primary instead of a Copy, but that is not always possible... so you CAN do your validation (even backups) on a copy... using a copy is better than doing Nothing... but keep in mind, what you do on a copy is not 100% the same as doing it on the primary.

Using a separate system to test your backups can be very useful (a backup that you CANNOT restore is useless and gives a false sense of security).